# Finding density of Haar measure relative to the Liouville volume measure on $\frac{G^{\mathbb{C}}}{P}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, measure-theory, symmetric-spaces

Let $G$ be a connected compact Lie group and $G^{\mathbb{C}}$ be the complexification of the Lie group $G$ then we know that by polar decomposition we can write $G^{\mathbb{C}}\cong G\times \mathfrak{g}^*\cong G\times \mathfrak{g} \cong  TG\cong T^*G$ by $$G\times \mathfrak{g}\to G^{\mathbb{C}}$$ $$(x,Y)\mapsto x.\exp(iY)$$

Define the function $\mu:G^{\mathbb{C}}\to \mathbb{R} $
$$\mu(x,Y)=\left(\det \left(\frac{sin(ad(Y))}{ad(Y)}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ where $x\in G,Y\in\mathfrak{g}$. The function $\mu$ is non-negative real analytic function on $G^{\mathbb{C}}$. It is known that $\mu^2$ is density of Haar measure relative to the Liouville volume measure on $G^{\mathbb{C}}$. Now my question is

> How can we find the density of Haar measure relative to the Liouville
>   volume measure on $\frac{G^{\mathbb{C}}}{P}$ where $P$ is Parabolic
>   subgroup of $G^{\mathbb{C}}$. If there is some reference or idea
>   please let me know